# How to calculate a due date based on another date, a type of request, and a priority value

Tags: vba, excel

Today I am trying to figure out the best way to create a solution to my problem.
I am trying to generate a due date(column J). This due date is based off of another date(column N), so starting with that date I need to check for a priority level (column L), of which there are 4 different values. Levels of priority: 2,3,4, or 5. Priorities are column K. Then I need to check column C for the first two letters of the string. There are 3 different options that can come up in column C such as DR and SR and A4 but A4 can be ignored all together. Below are the formula's for DR and SR

```
DR'S --------------------------------------------------------

2A (or B) - Column N + 29 = Column J(The solution)
=DATE(YEAR(N29)+0,MONTH(N29)+0,DAY(N29)+29)

3A (or B) - Column N + 89 = cColumn J(The solution)
=DATE(YEAR(N29)+0,MONTH(N29)+0,DAY(N29)+89)

4A (or B) - Column N + 179 = Column J(The solution)
=DATE(YEAR(N29)+0,MONTH(N29)+0,DAY(N29)+179)

5A (or B) - Column N + 364 = Column J(The solution)
=DATE(YEAR(N29)+0,MONTH(N29)+0,DAY(N29)+364)

SR'S -----------------------------------------------------------

2A (or B) - Column N + 89 = Column J(The solution)
=DATE(YEAR(N29)+0,MONTH(N29)+0,DAY(N29)+89)

3A (or B) - Column N + 179 = Column J(The solution)
=DATE(YEAR(N29)+0,MONTH(N29)+0,DAY(N29)+179)

4A (or B) - Column N + 269 = Column J(The solution)
=DATE(YEAR(N29)+0,MONTH(N29)+0,DAY(N29)+279)

5A (or B) - Column N + 364 = Column J(The solution)
=DATE(YEAR(N29)+0,MONTH(N29)+0,DAY(N29)+364)
```

I was hoping to get a nudge in the right direction, and some insight of the best way to implement this.

[image]

Comment: column **M** or column **N** ?

Comment: This will probably be easier to understand if you can provide a sample of your sheet

Comment: Column M is the initial date, then using the priority level(column K) and the first 2 letters of  Column C, I would need the code to determine which formula to use then output the result as a date into column J.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/HWmUzTT.png 
I have omitted irrelevant data.

Comment: Are you using some type of foreign language keyboard that I'm unfamiliar with? Your dates in the image are clearly in column **N** not M and the priority level is in column **L** not K.

Comment: I forgot to take into account the additional cell for the output J, when I made the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=m29+if(left(c29, 2)="DR", choose(left(k29)-1, 29, 89, 179, 364), if(left(c29, 2)="SR", choose(left(k29)-1, 89, 179, 279, 364), 0))
```

May need to assert the target cell's formatting as a date otherwise you may receive an answer like 43,089.

Comment: I changed the (k29)-1 to (k29)-2 and it gave me a correct answer as an output.

Comment: CHOOSE starts its options at 1, not zero so the first priority (e.g. 2A or 2B) should be left(L29)-1, not left(L29)-2.

Comment: Right, I think I had a goof changed it back and now the output is correct.